# Connecting Multiple Clients to a Single SQL Server over LAN using WinForms?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, lan, multiple-instances

So I have successfully connected a client system which has a C# WinForms application with a SQL Server (through an Ethernet Cable) and have been able to read and update the database from the client system. I want to now extend this to a LAN network of multiple client systems but I am unsure of how to proceed in the right direction since I am fairly new to this. Is giving the server's IP and correct SQL Server Authentication credentials in the connection string of Windows Forms required for all the client systems only? Or are there additional settings and/ or configurations that I need to correctly establish a connection and update the database from any of the client's WinForms application? Also practically speaking, how many client systems can be connected to achieve such a network which does not compromise on efficiency? I am using SQL Server 2017.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want many systems running your WinForms application to connect a central single `SQL Server` instance ? That is very much possible, just provide the proper `connection string` as configuration setting to that application, and allow user to configure it via GUI as well. SQL Server can handle thousands of concurrent connections, and it is unlikely that you will exceed it. Doc says it handles max 32767 connections, per instance. In typical client-server architectures, the server side will use singe app specific account or role to connect, so unlikely to exceed.

Comment: SQL Server is designed to work with multiple clients simultaneously, there shouldn't be any problem connecting multiple clients to the same server.

Comment: What's the difference between "through an ethernet cable" and a "lan network"? if it's the same network, there should be no problems. If LAN network is somewhere else, there might be problems, depending if you can access the sql server from it or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want many client systems running your WinForms application to connect a central single SQL Server instance. Yes, that is very much possible, just provide the proper connection string as configuration setting to that application, and you could allow admin user to configure it via GUI as well. SQL Server can handle thousands of concurrent connections, and it is unlikely that you will exceed it. SQL Server documentation says it handles max 32767 connections, per instance. In typical client-server architectures, the server side will use singe app specific account or role to connect, so you are unlikely to exceed. The connection string could have IP address of the SQL server, or a fully qualified domain name[FQDN]. That is more preferable for enterprise scenarios, so that you do not depend on specific IP address.